# "like doing" vs. "like to do"

Tags: verbs, infinitives, gerunds

> I like to play tennis on Tuesdays.
>
> I like playing tennis on Tuesdays.

Having taken into account the following, would you please throw a light on what is the difference between the sentences above?

This question was inspired by a comment left on a similar question I asked [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/43992/differentiating-between-would-like-and-like-to), where a user said:

> *Like playing* vs. *like to play* is the question of gerund vs. infinitive. Both of those are correct, but I don't think there's a general rule.

So, is there some general rule? Or was the comment correct?

Comment: Related (on ELU): [When should a verb be followed by a gerund instead of an infinitive?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/329/26083) (See the "Verbs Followed by Either Gerund or Infinitive" heading, about halfway down.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can say "I like to do something or I like doing something; it means the same.
But when you talk about your habbies or interests, you usually use the -ing form of the verb after "like".

So it's more idiomatic if you say "I like playing tennis on Tuesdays".

Comment: This is not at all correct.  They're both equally *idiomatic*.  You might have a *personal* or *dialect* preference for one or the other, but it could be the opposite with another person or another dialect.

Comment: @Andrew, You are right. I have edited my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

They're both exactly the same. They're both grammatically correct, and they both have the same meaning. There's not even a difference in emphasis! *Maybe* the version with the infinitive sounds slightly more formal.

Comment: So, is the following odd? I like to play tennis on Tuesdays.

Comment: @nima No, that's not odd. It's perfectly normal.